# How can I know if a Class is mapped as a Hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Object. How can I know if its class is mapped to a table in Hibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** My original answer works but will initialise unitialised proxies, which may be undesirable.

Better solution

```
boolean isHibernateEntity = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata( HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy( yourObject ) ) != null;
```

**Original answer:**

```
boolean isHibernateEntity = sessionFactory.getClassMetdata( Hibernate.getClass( yourObject ) ) != null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This way you can get all entities managed by Hibernate: `sessionFactory.getMetamodel()`. So to sum up:

```
boolean isHibernateEntity(Object obj) {
    Class<?> cl = HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(obj);
    for (EntityType<?> entity : sessionFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities())
        if (entity.getJavaType().equals(cl))
            return true;
    return false;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can identify if a class is an entity or not by `javax.persistence.metamodel.Metamodel` from JPA 2.0. Or `org.hibernate.Metamodel` if you do not use JPA. Example:

```
public boolean isEntity(Class<?> clazz){
    Metamodel metamodel = entityManager.getMetamodel();
    try {
        metamodel.entity(clazz);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // NOTE: the exception means the class is NOT an entity. There is no reason to log it.
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And here without `sessionFactory` :

```
private boolean isEntityClass(Object o){
    if(o != null){
        Type[] interfaces = o.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
        for(Type interf : interfaces)
            if(interf.equals(HibernateProxy.class))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't say if the object is an entity, it only says if it's a proxy.